# PHPUnit and Jenkins: Datetime expected and Datetime actual

Tags: datetime, jenkins, phpunit

I have the test class:

```
class ClassTest extends \PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
   /**
     * @covers \Path\Class::method()
     * @dataProvider methodData
     */
    public function testMethod($data, $expected)
    {
        $this->object = $this->getMockBuilder("Path\Class")
            ->setConstructorArgs([..])
            ->getMock();
        ....
        $response = $this->object->method($data);
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $response);
    }
    public function methodData()
    {
        $entity= new Entity();
        $entity->setDateArrivee(new \DateTime());
        ....
        ....
    }
}
```

I run the PHPunit in Jenkins job. the datetime of dateArrivee in the response and the expected is not same. I don't know why.
Can you help me ?

Comment: It will largely depend on how you are returning data from the `methodData()` data-provider, as well as what is happening in the method() being called. ClockMock-ing or storing the initialisation datetime for use in the function, and as the $expected return will also help.

Comment: Are you creating `DateTime` instance many times in your dataprovider/tests? If so, there might be small differences between them ((micro)seconds). Make sure the date is generated with the same timestamp, for example by hard coding it (currently you use the current timestamp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I write this method in the testMethod

```
$entity->setDateArrivee(new \DateTime());
```